# MTA 554 daily report via POSTFIX or log monitoring?

Tags: postfix, sendmail

It would be helpful to get a daily report of `554` coded email problems from postfix or other MTA programs, ie. if some mail servers think you are blacklisted, they will tell you details with urls on the 554 line

Has anyone come up with such a utility?

This way you could become aware of delivery problems before users have problems with things like resetting passwords, etc.

I thought it would be possible to `grep` the `/var/log/maillog` but I do not see `554` status codes in there, apparently it only logs actually sent mail - unless maybe there is a more verbose logging option

ps. someone please create the MTA tag

Comment: Many folks use [pflogsum](http://linxnet.com/postfix_contrib.html) to report on this data, but that assumes your syslog server is running and properly sending the mail facility to where you expect it.  If you are not seeing 4xx/5xx codes in syslog, then either it is not running or is misconfigured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many folks use [pflogsum](http://linxnet.com/postfix_contrib.html) to report on postfix log data, but that assumes your syslog server is running and properly sending the mail facility to where you expect it.

If you are not seeing 4xx/5xx codes in syslog, then either it is not running or is misconfigured.  You would need to resolve this problem first.  First verify which syslog daemon is running, then check the associated configuration of said daemon to determine where to point pflogsum.

Comment: Looks like pflogsum can just be told to look directly at `/var/log/maillog` so it works. Thanks for that lead, makes a nice report.

Comment: No problem.   There are other tools listed on that page as well.